# why to cast pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I have a little basic question about C pointers and casting.
I didn't understand why should I cast the pointers?

I just tried this code and I got the same output for each option:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x = 3;
    int *y = &x;
    double *s;

    option 1: s = (double*)y;
    option 1: printf("%p, %d\n", (int*)s, *((int*)s));
    option 2: s = y;
    option 2: printf("%p, %d", s, *s);

    return 0;
}
```

My question is why do I have to do: `s = (double*)y`?
Intuitively, the address is the same for all the variables. The difference should be about how many bytes to read from this address. Also, about the printing - if I use `%d` it will take automatically as an `int`.

Why do I need to cast it as an `int*`?
Am I wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to assign a pointer to an `int` variable into a `double*`?

Comment: Use `%p` to print pointers.

Comment: The code you show is broken. That's why you need to use a hammer like casting to probalby get it working. In C one very rarely needs to cast.

Comment: I'm learning c now, and it's really important to me to understand how it works.

Comment: It doesn't work. It is broken. Look up "strict aliasing".

Comment: Just do not try to make code complie by casting around wildly. It's almost ever a sign of something being sub-optimal, to not say wrong.

Comment: to my understanding you are violating strict aliasing rules

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not an english speaker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a great deal of confusion in your question. `int` and `double` are different things: they represent numbers in memory using different bit patterns and in most cases even a different number of bytes. The compiler produces code that converts between these representations when you implicitly or explicitly require that:

```
int x = 3;
double d;

d = x;          // implicit conversion from integer representation to double
d = (double)x;  // explicit conversion generates the same code
```

Here is a more subtle example:

```
d = x / 2;      // equivalent to d = (double)(x / 2);
```

will store the double representation of `1` into `d`.  Whereas this:

```
d = (double)x / 2;  // equivalent to d = (double)x / 2.0;
```

will store the double representation of `1.5` into `d`.

Casting pointers is a completely different thing. It is not a conversion, but merely a coertion.  You are telling the compiler to trust you know what you are doing.  It does not change the address they point to, not does it affect the bytes in memory at that address.  C does not let you store a pointer to int into a pointer to double because it is most likely an error: When you dereference the pointer using the wrong type, the content of memory is interpreted the wrong way, potentially yielding a different value or even causing a crash.

You can override the compiler's refusal by using an explicit cast to `(double*)`, but you are asking for trouble.

When you later dereference `s`, you may access invalid memory and the value read is definitely meaningless.

Further confusion involves the `printf` function: the format specifiers in the format string are promisses by the programmer about the actual value types he passes as extra parameters.

```
printf("%p,%d",s,*s)
```

Here you pass a `double` (with no meaningful value) and you tell printf you passed an `int`. A blatant case of multiple undefined behaviour. Anything can happen, including printf producing similar output as the other option, leading to complete confusion.  On 64 bit Intel systems, the way doubles and ints are passed to printf is different and quite complicated.

To avoid this kind of mistake in printf, compile with -Wall. gcc and clang will complain about type mismatches between the format specifiers and the actual values passed to printf.

As others have commented, you should not use pointer casts in C.  Even the typical case `int *p = (int *)malloc(100 * sizeof(int))` does not require a cast in C.

Comment: There is one single case that  routinely needs casts, though: object oriented code. There is just no way around an occasional downcast when you do polymorphism in C.

Comment: Of course there are some cases where pointer casts are needed.  For example, you cannot implement `strchr` in C without a cast to remove the constness of the parameter (OK, a union will do the trick, but non portably).  Polymorphism is another more elaborate example.  I just cannot think of one that the OP would encounter, given his level of understanding of the language.

Comment: It may be the case that the OP is not yet advanced enough to get into situations where a cast is required and a good idea. However, saying "you should not use pointer casts in C" is a bit too general. I'd rather say something along the lines of: "There are very few situations that actually require a cast, and if a cast can be avoided, it should be avoided. Most simple code will not need any casts."

Answer (score 0):

Explicit pointer casting is necessary to avoid compiler warnings. And compiler warnings on pointer type conflict exist to show possible bugs. With pointer casting you tell the compiler: "I know what I am doing here..."

Comment: Works for MSVC. On GCC there's a strict aliasing on >=O2 that can possibly break the code.

Comment: Thanks. So you're saying that if I'll ignore the warnings, the program should run ok?

Comment: Not at all.  read my answer.  Warnings are the compiler's hints about programmer's bugs and confusion.  You should enable more warnings and never ignore them.  If you don't understand a warning, you don't understand the code.

Comment: Fix your code until no more warnings are issued. Do not using wild and clueless casting to apply such fixes!

Comment: @dvirnaim The program will run but it is best to have 0 warnings.

Comment: I know. I'm sure this isn't the optimal program but through this program I understand the pointers-issue better.